# ngAnimate transition scrolls current page to top in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, slide, ng-animate

When I click next button which is down below on one of my views to go to another state, the current page where I'm at scrolls back to the top then finally ngAnimate and css starts to slide the 2 partials. However, I don't like the resulting transitions as it causes somewhat a flickering effect.

What I'd like to happen is that when I click next button, I'd like to maintain the position of where current view is on the screen, then start the sliding.

Is there something I need to change on my code? autoscroll="false" on my ui-view doesn't seem to help.

Here is my new css.

```
 #content-view.ng-enter, #content-view.ng-leave {
    position: absolute;
    // width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
  }
  #content-view.ng-enter {
    // transform: translateX(100%);
    // -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  #content-view.ng-enter-active {
    // transform: translateX(0);
    // -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  #content-view.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateX(0);
    // -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  #content-view.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateX(-100%);
    // -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 50, 50); 
  }
```

Here is a plunker but I'm not sure why it's not happening here. There might be something in my code that's doing the behavior.

Anyways, I like the behavior of this one when switching between view. However, I was hoping if we can correctly position the new target view when we click it. Right now, if let's say i'm displaying view1 and I scroll it down, once I click view 2, I want the position of view1 to stay as is but I want the position of view 2 to proper top position and not the same position as view1.

http://plnkr.co/edit/thDO1WZ9YUcV9yGfkVjh?p=preview

## UPDATE:

Here is the solution on how I got it to work. I love the slide transition. It really looks so professional.

## Snippet from main.html

```
<div id="content-view" ng-class="{ 'backEvent' : $root.backEvent === true, 'entryComplete' : $root.entryComplete === true  }" ui-view="content" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Initial load of the form, $scope.entryComplete is set to false. When I fill out the form and click next, $scope.entryComplete becomes true. I set it in the controller. Since it became true, these 2 classes will be used, #content-view.entryComplete.ng-enter and #content-view.entryComplete.ng-enter-active.

Now when I click Back button, $root.entryComplete becomes false and $root.backEvent becomes true. Now that entryComplete is gone, these will be used #content-view.ng-enter and #content-view.ng-enter-active and for the ng-leave, these will be used #content-view.backEvent.ng-leave and #content-view.backEvent.ng-leave-active. I set backEvent back to false when I click Next again

## Here is part of the magic that I've worked all day.

```
#content-view.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#content-view.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#content-view.ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#content-view.ng-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

#content-view.entryComplete.ng-enter {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#content-view.entryComplete.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#content-view.backEvent.ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

#content-view.backEvent.ng-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

Don't forget about the other magic that I mentioned somewhere in the thread, the one that will store the current Y(top) coordinate value.

```
var offsets = document.getElementById('content-view').getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById('content-view').style.top = (offsets.top - 65) + 'px';
```

I took out the .style.position = "absolute" since I already got it hardcoded in the css. Enjoy!

Comment: please provide relevant html and js code, or a plunker/fiddle

Comment: I made changes and wrote a comment as well.

Comment: thanks, it is now easier to understand the issue

Comment: Great! So yeah, target view should always be displayed properly and for the current view, we can just leave the current position of it that while we are sliding it away out of our screen. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but upon reading your question I thought about UI-Router's [autoscroll directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#autoscroll). Maybe setting it to false will help?

Comment: I mentioned autoscroll on my post above Sunil :)

Comment: I did more diggging. This is the exact code that changes the current view's position when I click Next. It's from angular.js - http://i.imgur.com/6ekAT2a.png

Comment: I will not have time to try and answer this today; however, the solution I envision involves a javaScript-based animation, that would set/get the scroll position using element.scrollTop; you would need to store the value of a view's scrollTop into a service variable, to reset the scroll when a previous view is called: a rather complex solution. I hope someone finds something easier/more elegant

Answer (score 0):

this may be what you're looking for?

```
$scope.gotoTop = function() {
  $location.hash('top');
  $anchorScroll();
};
```

add this function to the controller of your navbar and add the function to each of your links.

`<a ng-click="gotoTop()" href="#/home">Example</a>`

Example `NavCtrl.js`

```
angular.module('app').controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    $scope.gotoTop = function() {
      $location.hash('top');
      $anchorScroll();
    };

}]);
```

Comment: I actually have this code $window.scrollTo(0, 0); and it's working really well. However, I have it in $stateChangeStart. Maybe I should move it to success and see if it changes the behavior. However, that scrollTo code is currently disabled. I did some digging and I found the code that changes the position of the current view I'm at. I am not sure why it's happening since it's not happening in my plunker example. http://i.imgur.com/6ekAT2a.png

Comment: if my views were actually fit inside the browser window's height, I would not have this UX issue. Unfortunately, our designer made the view longer than the height of the browser and I understand why she made it that way. It was acceptable. It's actually working but flickering or jumping makes my application look elementary. :)

Comment: i think i'm having the same issues with the animations on my application, but i'm just learning AngularJS still.. 14k lines of code on your img.. lol http://cisweb.ufv.ca/~300105626/bcoapo2/#/home

Comment: lol, that 14k lines is from angular code though mine is close to 8k too, not just angular but html, scss, etc :)

Comment: I think I'm very close at getting it to work. After adding left and top css properties to one of the classes, .ng-leave, I saw how the divs behaved. I can dynamically update the left/top via Angular. I'm now playing with getBoundingClientRect() which returns to me the coordinates. :)

Comment: Extremely happy, I got it working :) http://pastebin.com/iEsGmn4m All I need to do is add a class so that I can distinguish between next button and back button. I'll only add a new ng-class if back-button was click. I'll have a new css for it. The slide transition will be from left to right when I click back.

Comment: Finally I'm done! I added 2 classes, one for back event and the other one when entry to the form is complete. It is required in order to distinguish between a plain content-view.ng-leave or content-view.ng-enter vs content-view.formDone.ng-enter. If you don't do this, you won't be able to customize your css since nganimate will always add ng-enter. I added a class so that its css specificity will become the most relevant and my css entry for the higher css specificity will take in effect. I'll update my code above.

Comment: well done :) first time seeing the `.getBoundingClientRect()`method for me ^^